# Appened is not working with calling id which is unique

Tags: javascript, php, html, append

This my code when click the button i want to display button dynamic id to the specific place by calling that id:
this is my code:

```
<span  id="2" class="view-details">View Details</span>
$( ".view-details" ).on( "click", function() {
var group = field.attr("id");
console.log(group);                     //Ex: value is coming as "2"
$("#groupID").append( group );
```

My HTML

```
 <span id="groupID"></span>             //i want to display the value "2" here
```

Comment: your question is not clear can you please give clear explanation regarding that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `field` variable is not defined instead of that use `this` to refer the clicked element and get `id` property. Althogh for updating the content use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) method since [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method just insert the new content at end(existing content would be there).

```js
$(".view-details").on("click", function() {
  // get id property
  var group = this.id;

  // update the html contecnt of span element
  // or use `text()` method
  $("#groupID").html(group);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="2" class="view-details">View Details 1</span><br>
<span id="3" class="view-details">View Details 2</span><br>
<span id="groupID"></span>
```

Comment: it worked thanks for the snippet..Can you please tell what is wrong in append..?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed : that wouldn't remove the existing content... i.e, content would get appended on each click.... 2,22,222,...

Answer (score 3):

If we look only the snippet you provided, the issue is that you are not defining the field variable. However it will keep appending the 2 in your span as many times as you click if that is not desired , the other answer is already taking care of that.

```js
$( ".view-details" ).on( "click", function() {
field = $(this);
var group = field.attr("id");
console.log(group);                     //Ex: value is coming as "2"
$("#groupID").append( group ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span  id="2" class="view-details">View Details</span>
<span id="groupID"></span>
```